# lxml installs but module is not found in python script

Tags: python, pip, lxml

I installed lxml with `sudo pip install lxml` just fine, i checked that it was indeed installed with `pip list` and it was listed with version 3.6.1.

When i run the a script called `cubemximporter.py` it says

`ImportError: No module named lxml`

I tried uninstalling lxml and installing with easy_install but got the same thing.

I tried installing with `STATIC_DEPS=true sudo pip install lxml` as described [here](http://lxml.de/installation.html) but i still get the same issue.

What is even weirder is if i just do "python" in terminal to open the interpretter and type "from lxml import etree" it gives no error at all!

Comment: What OS and version of python do you use?

Comment: OSX 10.11.6 Python 2.7.11